# Populate a C# class from a dataset with multiple linked tables using linq lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to populate a list (`lstContractor`) of a C# class (`contractor`), containing fields and lists, from a `DataSet` returned from SQL. The `DataSet` returns multiple tables, linked by an id.

I've managed to get it all working except 1 field, which is the only field I need from the table it is in.  When I'm trying to select it using LINQ, I'm getting `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.String]` instead of the contents of the field.

My Code looks like this:

```
    lstContractor = dsContractor.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(contractor => new Contractor
    {
        intContractorId = contractor.Field<int>("ID"),
        strFirstName = contractor.Field<string>("FirstName"),
        strLastName = contractor.Field<string>("LastName"),
        strProfile = dsContractor.Tables[7].AsEnumerable().Where(profile => profile.Field<int>("ContractorId") == contractor.Field<int>("Id")).
            Select(profile => profile.Field<string>("ContractorProfile")).ToString(),
        // populate addresses
        Address = dsContractor.Tables[6].AsEnumerable().Where(address => address.Field<int>("ContractorId") == contractor.Field<int>("Id")).
                Select(address => new Address
                {
                    intId = address.Field<int>("ContractorId"),
                    strAddressLine1 = address.Field<string>("AddressLine1"),
                    strAddressLine2 = address.Field<string>("AddressLine2"),
                    strAddressLine3 = address.Field<string>("AddressLine3"),
                    strAddressLine4 = address.Field<string>("AddressLine4"),
                    strAddressLine5 = address.Field<string>("AddressLine5"),
                    strPostCode = address.Field<string>("PostCode")
                }).ToList<Address>(),

        // populate industries
        Industry = dsContractor.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Where(Industry => Industry.Field<int>("ContractorId") == contractor.Field<int>("Id")).
            Select(target => new Industry
            {
                intId = target.Field<int>("ContractorId"),
                strIndustryName = target.Field<string>("IndustryName")
            }).ToList<Industry>(),

        // populate key skills
        KeySkill = dsContractor.Tables[2].AsEnumerable().Where(KeySkill => KeySkill.Field<int>("ContractorId") == contractor.Field<int>("Id")).
            Select(target => new KeySkill
            {
                intId = target.Field<int>("ContractorId"),
                strKeySkillName = target.Field<string>("KeySkillName")
            }).ToList<KeySkill>(),

        // populate email addresses
        EmailAddress = dsContractor.Tables[3].AsEnumerable().Where(EmailAddress => EmailAddress.Field<int>("ContractorId") == contractor.Field<int>("Id")).
            Select(target => new EmailAddress
            {
                intId = target.Field<int>("ContractorId"),
                strEmailAddress = target.Field<string>("EmailAddress"),
                strEmailType = target.Field<string>("EmailType")
            }).ToList<EmailAddress>(),

        // populate phone numbers
        PhoneNumber = dsContractor.Tables[4].AsEnumerable().Where(PhoneNumber => PhoneNumber.Field<int>("ContractorId") == contractor.Field<int>("Id")).
            Select(target => new PhoneNumber
            {
                intId = target.Field<int>("ContractorId"),
                strPhoneNumberType = target.Field<string>("PhoneType"),
                strPhoneNumber = target.Field<string>("PhoneNumber")
            }).ToList<PhoneNumber>(),

        Geography = dsContractor.Tables[5].AsEnumerable().Where(PhoneNumber => PhoneNumber.Field<int>("ContractorId") == contractor.Field<int>("Id")).
                Select(target => new Geography
                {
                    intId = target.Field<int>("ContractorId"),
                    strGeography = target.Field<string>("GeographyName")
                }).ToList<Geography>(),


    }).ToList<Contractor>();
```

the class looks like this:

```
    public int intContractorId;
public string strFirstName;
public string strMiddleName;
public string strLastName;
public string strDescription; 
public DateTime dtDOB;
public string strGender;
public string strProfile;
public int intIsFullTime;
public int intWorkMonday;
public int intWorkTuesday;
public int intWorkWednesday;
public int intWorkThursday;
public int intWorkFriday;
public int intWorkSaturday;
public int intWorkSunday;
public DateTime dtAvailableFrom;
public int intActive;
public decimal dcSubscrptionCost;
public DateTime dtRenewalDate;
public List<Address> Address;
public List<EmailAddress> EmailAddress;
public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumber;
public List<KeySkill> KeySkill;
public List<Geography> Geography;
public List<Industry> Industry;
public List<SubIndustry> SubIndustry;
```

The field in question is `strProfile`, but I can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting the contents that I am, instead of the string the the field contains.

I've checked in debug mode, and the correct data is in the `DataSet`.

Please let me know if I've missed anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
...Select(profile => profile.Field<string>("ContractorProfile")).ToString()
```

Linq's `Select()` returns an IEnumerable, so `ToString()` is just going to try to tell you that it's an IEnumerable. If you want the first item from the returned collection, use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
...Select(profile => profile.Field<string>("ContractorProfile")).First().ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting an enumeration of rows using `Where`, then selecting a string from each row, then finally calling `ToString()` on the enumerable. Perhaps you meant to use `Single` instead of `Where`:

```
strProfile = dsContractor.Tables[7].AsEnumerable()
    .Single(profile => profile.Field<int>("ContractorId") == contractor.Field<int>("Id"))
    .Select(profile => profile.Field<string>("ContractorProfile")),
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb342451.aspx) method instead of `ToString()`, becuase your query returns an `IEnumerable`:

```
strProfile = dsContractor.Tables[7].AsEnumerable().Where(profile => profile.Field<int>("ContractorId") == contractor.Field<int>("Id")).
            Select(profile => profile.Field<string>("ContractorProfile")).SingleOrDefault();
```

**EDIT:**

Becuase you used `ToString()` I assumed you was sure that the query returns 1 element. Infact you should use this solution only if you're completely sure that your query returns a **maximum of 1 element** else it gives an excpetion. If it returns more than one result you should use [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) method which returns the first element else the default type value.